# Any way to mathematically express the set of all argmin(f(x))?

Tags: optimization, notation, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

my question is: 
I would like to express in a mathematical way the first $argmin(f(x))$. The function $argmin$ returns the argument for the global minima, but, there is any way to express the set of all arguments that produce local minimums?

I would like to write an expression like $first argmin = min(argSmin(f(x)))$.

I hope my question is clear...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yess, thanks user202729, I add "notation" in tags.

Comment: Hint: Have you found out a way to express the minimum reachable value of $f$?

Comment: I have not seen standard notation for the set of local minima, so you should probably just create your own and define it for your readers.

Comment: done @LinAlg, thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I can answer "is any way to express the set of all arguments that produce local minimums?":

Let $f : X \to Y$. The set of local minimizers is:
$$\{ x \in X : \exists \varepsilon > 0 : f(x) \leq f(z) \; \forall z \in X, ||z-x|| \leq \varepsilon \}.$$

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks @LinAlg ! the answer to my question is the minimum of this set. So:

$$ \[ \min(y),  y = \{ x \in X : \exists \varepsilon > 0 : f(x) \leq f(z) \; \forall z \in X, ||z-x|| \leq \varepsilon \} \] $$

Comment: @AntonioCC Do you have $X \subset \mathbb{R}$? Otherwise how do you define the minimum?

Comment: @AntonioCC this notation is shorter: $$\min\{ x \in X : \exists \varepsilon > 0 : f(x) \leq f(z) \; \forall z \in X, ||z-x|| \leq \varepsilon \}.$$

Answer (score 0):

My notation is also that $\arg \min$ returns a set. If you chose differently you can write:
$firstmin_D f=\min\lbrace x\in D, x=\min_D f\rbrace$